# Why 'return' is not working in generator method?

Tags: python

```
def function(list):

    for x in list:
        yield x

    return 4

list = [1,2,3]
object = function(list)
print(next(object))
print(next(object))
print(next(object))
print(next(object))
```

In this code when I'm calling function for the 4th time I'm getting error.

But when I replace `return 4` to `yield 4` then it's working properly.

Why that's happening?
On the 4th call the for loop get exited and next line `return 4` executed. Then what's the problem?

Comment: If you want to yield a thing, use `yield`. `return` doesn't yield.

Comment: That's what's *supposed* to happen: [*"In a generator function, the return statement indicates that the generator is done and will cause StopIteration to be raised."*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement)

Comment: This isn't like [Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/9.1.html), where both `coroutine.yield` and `return` send values to the `coroutine.resume` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to yield, and prematurely exit the function, you can use a bare `return` after you yielded:

```
def function(ls):
    for x in ls:
        yield x
    yield 4
    return
    some_code(that_wont, be_executed)
```

Generators don't return values, they yield them. The only reason to use `return` in a generator is to abort the execution / raise a `StopIteration` to signal to the caller that there are no more values.